# Creating an API in yii for cross domain communication

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, rest, yii

I am planning to create a Restful API in yii for cross domain communication. As what I have researched, cross domain communication can only be done via jsonp and my implementation is as follows:

UsersController:: actionCrossDomain

```
public function actionCrossDomain(){
   $this->layout=false;
   $data['data']['User']['name']= 'Johny';
   $this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($data),'application/json');

}
```

UsersController::_sendResponse methdod it is the same as you can see in :[Click here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/#hh12)

On another server that i configured using virtual host, I am invoking the above method via ajax:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "jsonp",
           url:'http:'http//uxaserver.local/alpha2/app/users/crossDomain' ,
           data: null,
           processData: false,
           crossDomain: true,
           contentType: "application/json",
           success: function (data) {
                     console.log("done");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                         console.log(request);
                   }
        });
});
```

The issue is my firebug is is complaining that :

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
```

My requirement is such because I am helping my client's to do some customized analytic to his other websites and I need to put a script in his web pages of different domains so that the analytic data is recorded in the main server. I understand that I need to use the rest interface to communicate thus I am taking this approach. I am not sure if I have taken the right approach and please advice. I want to make it in a way where a client has an api key and can communicate with the api provided by me.

Is there any other approach to do this? Rather than jsonp?

Comment: You could try getJson http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ end your url with `callback=?` And make sure your response is `$get['callback'].'('.yourJSONData.')'`

Comment: Here is how you would do it with YII: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587301/yii-async-jsonp-request

Comment: I have tried that but i am wondering if this is the right approach for api calls by the clients

Comment: yes, that is how jsonp works. you can try cors headers but it's not supported in jquery (with IE) because IE doens't properly support it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP A link to cors: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

As i see this string contents error

```
url:'http:'http//uxaserver.local/alpha2_uxarmy/app/users/crossDomain' ,
```

Should be

```
url:'http//uxaserver.local/alpha2_uxarmy/app/users/crossDomain' ,
```